# Save Entity Using JPARepository

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am new to JpaRepository. I have a class StudentClient.java, where I am inserting records using Hibernate.

My question is , if I want to use JpaRepository, how can I do this??

I want to insert the records and then save the entity using Jparepository. Code-

```
public class StudentClient
    {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
      {                                           
        // create Configuration class, Configuration object parses and reads .cfg.xml file                                                   
        Configuration c = new Configuration();
        c.configure("/hibernate.cfg.xml");
        // SessionFactory holds cfg file properties like, driver props and hibernate props and mapping file                                                 
        SessionFactory sf=c.buildSessionFactory();
        // create one session means Connection
        Session s = sf.openSession();
        // before starting save(),update(), delete() operation we need to start TX, starting tx mean    con.setAutoCommit(false);                                             
        Transaction tx = s.beginTransaction();     
        try
        {
          Student std1=new Student();
          std1.setSid(100);
          std1.setSname("S N Rao");
          std1.setSmarks(78);
          std1.setSjoindate(new Date());     
          Student std2=new Student();
          std2.setSid(101);  
          std2.setSname("Sumathi");
          std2.setSmarks(52);
          std2.setSjoindate(new Date());     
          s.save(std1);      // stmt.addBatch("INSERT INTO school VALUES (....)");
          s.save(std2);     
          s.flush(); // stmt.executeBatch()
          tx.commit(); // con.commit();
          System.out.println("Records inserted");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
          tx.rollback();    // con.rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are creating new Spring based application, you should use Spring Boot. For Spring Boot based application your heavy lifting code will not be relevant, because Spring Boot + Spring + Spring Data combo will do it for you.

To start familiarize yourself to Spring ecosystem support for persistence,  take a look at [this Spring Data JPA guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/).

Comment: So I can insert records using setter methods and then save the ebtity using JPARepository, right?

Comment: *entity. Another question : can I use jdbcTemplate and jparepository , both in the same class?? Is it possible? I need to execute certain DDL statements using jdbcTemplate and I also need to insert records using JpaRepository.

Comment: Yes, you just fill in your Entity with desired data and call `jpaRepository.save`.

Comment: I highly recommend NOT to mix Hibernate with JdbcTemplate. Use one or the other.